# visual basic - where to find list of .dll references within Excel editor

Tags: vba

I've inherited a legacy Visual Basic application, that's embedded in an Excel sheet, that I need to modify.

I installed Microsoft Visual Basic 6 and then exported, one-by-one, the files from Excel to Visual Basic 6 IDE.

The project builds and runs within Excel but I get an error when I try to run it from Visual Basic 6:

> Compile error: User-defined type not defined

VB6 complains about the line `Dim CCPDevices() As VisionDeviceComponent`

The type `VisionDeviceComponent` only appears on this one line.

**QUESTION**

From the Visual Basic editor in Excel, how do I see the list of `.dll`s, etc. that `VisionDeviceComponent` comes from so I can add it in the VB6 project?

Comment: In Excel VBE you can go to `Tools`>>`References` and in there the ones that are checked are available for use in that VBAProject.

Comment: Note that VBA7 can work with 64-bit libraries, VB6/VBA6 can't.

Comment: @JNevill yep that’s it! Please reply as an answer.